# Azure Key Vault permission issue

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

[Access policy screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUBaD.jpg) The user,group or application ;appid=a9********bf70ea978d0;oid=a9******cb326;iss=https://sts.windows.net/14-e16e********6cacee8; does not have secrets list permission on key vault #39;t**ds;location=centralindia;t permission on key vault?

I'm getting this error.I have created created access policy for list and get secrets from vault.

Comment: hello @Mansi, Please add the user/ service principal in access policy for the keyvault. if its added please share the access policy screenshot in the question.

Comment: Are you using an application or a user? Check the issuer that the tenant id matches the Key Vault subscription tenant.

Comment: Hello @AnsumanBal-MT , I have added the screenshot of accesspolicy. Please check.

Comment: Hello @juunas , I'm using a User.

Comment: Thanks @MANSI, May i know what operation you are trying using the user and how you are doing it ? like from az-cli or powershell or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

I logged into Azure CLI with my service principal which does not have access to key vault.

I tried to list the secrets in the key vault and got the same error as yours:

[image]

I logged out and again logged in with my account which has access to list the secrets in the key vault.

I am able to list the secrets successfully.

[image]

You can log in to Azure CLI with your account which has key vault secrets list permission and list the secrets.

You would be able to list the secrets successfully